# Mod rewrite for fake subdomains?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I really tried tons of methods but i'm not successful.
I want a .Htaccess code to do the following :

I want to rename this : http://www.mydomain.com/media --> http://media.mydomain.com

So, By example instead of calling this : http://www.mydomain.com/media/XXX/picture.jpg
i will call : http://media.mydomain.com/XXX/picture.jpg

Thank you

Comment: You might get better answers on http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna be like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com%1$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure rewrite_module is loaded, something like;

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then add the following (to your .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)(.*) http://$1.mydomain.com$2 [L,R]
```

The Cond will only match www.mydomain.com. The Rule then will split the URL into 2 using the first '/' (which will be included in $2), rewrite and redirect.

Comment: @niry: I believe you've answered the reverse of what the OP wants (but I can't tell for sure), e.g. the user enters `sub.domain/blah` and the server serves `domain/sub/blah`.  (BTW, backticks work for code as in your last comment.)

Answer (score -1):

If you want the opposite (see Roger's comment) and without redirecting the user

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 !^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
RewriteRule   ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com(.*)  http://www.mydomain.com/$1$2 [L]
```

Also, see here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/rewriteguide.html