# Fake a subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to issue a redirect using `.htaccess` so that, for example, a user enters url:

```
http://demo.mysite.com
```

But what is actually being displayed resides at:

```
http://mysite.com/users/demo/
```

Have looked at other questions on here but they seem to go the other way.

The goal is to give users the simplest possible URL to share their site.

Or should I simply set up a PHP URL reader which moves users when they enter that URL (or any fake subdomain)

**UPDATE** Tried both of the following but neither works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.com/users/%1$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/users/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: your questions answers is here.check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444867/mod-rewrite-for-fake-subdomains?rq=1

Comment: check virtual host: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/subdomains/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Will rewrite any sub domain to the corresponding folder.

edit, actually if you want to hide the fact that you are redirecting to a folder you need to use mod_proxy

Comment: Thanks, but not working, rewrite definitely turned on. Results in DNS error from ISP

Comment: Are you pointing the subdomain at your server?

Comment: Try ping demo.mysite.com and ping mysite.com.  make sure they are the same ip address.

Comment: No, as the post says, I want to FAKE it - I know I can add it for each account but would rather not as its a lot of work for little reward, so I want a simple redirect.

Comment: THINK about it, if pinging the two domains returns DIFFERENT IP's then how does your browser know where to go.

Comment: Also there is SUCH thing as a wildcard domain entry in your dns zone file.  You can direct any subdomain for a DOMAIN to a particular IP or hostname.

Comment: Sorted it, many thanks for the info re wildcard DNS, that's what was needed - added a subdomain - *.mysite.com - and all good now.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is how you do that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite\.com/users/demo [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine on
```

// Extract the subdomain part of domain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
```

// Check that the subdomain part is not www and ftp and mail

```
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
```

// Redirect all requests to a address using the subdomain

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.com/users/%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working, rewrite definitely turned on. Results in DNS error from ISP