# redirect fake subdomain url to a specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

In my website, I provide user profiles and separate URL for them. That is, if my website URL is `www.sample.com` and if `user1` is logged in, the page will redirect to `www.user1.sample.com`. But this is not a sub-domain. I just want to go to a folder `user` if URL like `www.*.sample.com` occurs. And all the works will do in the `user` folder by keeping the URL as it is. Is there any way to do this using `.htaccess`?? I am not familier with `htaccess`. As general, I made an htaccess like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sample.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
Options -Multiviews
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^404/$ ./404.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

This code works perfect. And this is for work whwn the user enter `www.sample.com`. Can I do this for `www.*.sample.com` in the same `.htaccess` file.

I had gone through [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444867/mod-rewrite-for-fake-subdomains). But this too not working

Any help is appreciated..Thank you in advance

Comment: Please indicate if www.user1.sample.com resolves at the moment. Your webserver and the DNS have to be configured for that url to resolve to the correct path on the webserver. Only if that works is when you can do something with .htacecss.

Comment: Thnks for the reply...will try that...